# How to get "who's different" in a vector, with R

Tags: r

Simple question. Consider this vector:

```
[1] 378 380 380 380 380 360 187 380
```

How could we determine what are the numbers that differs from the others in that list? In that case it would be 378 360 and 187. Any ideas? I'm aware that the solution might not be simple...

I'm learning R and working on a dataset for my research, so it's != homework.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Congrats! You asked the 10,000th question on SO tagged in the R language. Sadly, the only prize is a good answer.

Comment: AHahah, that's great ! I consider getting a good answer is a FABULOUS price ! ;)

Comment: Great -- this is the second straight question I've browsed which calls itself the 1e4th :-) (see comments about tagging at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324869/how-do-i-determine-the-author-of-an-r-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the most frequent entry by using `table()` and `which.max()`, you can then index the original vector with a logical vector containing the non-equal entries like so: data[data!=mostfrequent]. You can get help by `?table()` and `?which.max()`, please comment if you need more.

Your sample vector

```
x <- c(378, 380, 380, 380, 380, 360, 187, 380)
```

Find the frequency of each number in it with `table`.  For convenience later on, we convert it to be a data frame.

```
counts <- as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`which.max` lets us locate the modal value (the most common one).

```
modal_value <- which.max(counts$Freq)
```

The other values can then be found via indexing.

```
as.numeric(counts[-modal_value, "x"])
```

Comment: Ok, I learned from this solution. Now would it be possible to apply this solution to an entire dataframe or matrix ? Maybe I should post another question with sample dataset...

Comment: @Chargaff Yes, a new question would also put it up again in the homepage-list.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe another alternative:

```
x <- c(378, 380, 380, 380, 380, 360, 187, 380)
setdiff(unique(x), x[duplicated(x)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Extracting unrepeated elements can be done with something like:

```
a<-c(378, 380, 380, 380, 380, 360, 187, 380)
b <- table(a)
names(b[b==1])
#[1] "187" "360" "378"
```

Comment: If "who's different" means "those that only occur once" then this answer is probably best. If "who's different" means "every value but the most frequent one" then see mine. OP should clarify that.

Comment: Yes, interesting comment, I should have phrased my question as "every value but the most frequent one". THanx for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach:

```
x <- c(378, 380, 380, 380, 380, 360, 187, 380)
y <- rle(sort(x)); y[[2]][y[[1]]==1]
```

Comment: This approach should be pretty fast and also returns numeric values

Comment: excuse me sorting is O(nlogn), accumulating, finding the maximum and indexing is O(n)

Comment: @eznme And finding alternative ways to accomplish a task is fun!  I actually find Tyler's approach to be fun.  I would be interested in benchmarking his approach against yours because table doesn't seem to be too efficient of a function.  Just FYI It's hard to tell if you were just pointing something out or trying to be insulting.

Comment: sorry, was just a remark. your alternate way of doing it also allows to e.g. say "who's different" means "all but the **two** most frequent ones"... so its more flexible.

Comment: Also, seeing as the vector only has 8 elements, speed shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: @Riche: but we always assume the example data is a small representative of the real thing :-) .