# How do I determine the author of an R package?

Tags: r

How can I determine who the authors of a package are? Given that we have this widely used code base, I think it is appropriate that I make a reference to the software I use in my analysis.

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the author and any other relevant information?

In pseudocode, I want to do the following:

```
references("base")
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The careful observer will notice that this is the 10,000th question with the [tag:r] tag. Thank you to R-core and all package authors who have made R the brilliant system that it is.

Comment: Technically this is the second 10000th question. The previous one was 10000, and then a question got retagged, and now you've brought it to 10000 again.  If we keep retagging questions can keep celebrating all day!

Comment: The Title of the question suggests a clear answer (@spacedman's from below; `packageDescription("foo")$Author`) yet the body muddies the water a bit. As far as R is concerned there is a clearly defined idea of what the Author is & that is in the `DESCRIPTION`. `citation()` really fully answers the Q, however, because it does one of two things i) if there is a `CITATION` file in the package it displays that, and if not present, it auto-generates a citation based on the `DESCRIPTION`. This wasn't immediately clear from Ritchie's Answer until I read `?citation`. One new thing I learned today! FTW

Comment: @RichieCotton Technically this the 3rd (or greater) 10K question.  1 was removed, 1 was retagged, and there was this one.   Who can know for sure?  It is but a sample.  :)

Comment: To follow up on Andrie's thanks to R-Core - in recognition of 10K Qs on SO - thanks also to all those who've made Stack Overflow a great place to ask R questions and to learn from the insights shared by so many others.  The list is quite long, but especially thanks to Mike Driscoll, JD Long, & Christopher DuBois for seeding many Qs and Dirk Eddelbuettel, Gavin Simpson, & David Winsemius for answering so many Qs. In addition, thanks to the R Core members and package developers who use SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have posted functions, and not explanations, I'll fill this in.

Distributed with every package is a DESCRIPTION file.  Optionally, a maintainer may include a CITATION file.

The `citation(pkgName)` (where `pkgName` is a character string) function will look for the CITATION file first, then the DESCRIPTION file.  If the former is found, it will present that file's contents.  If the latter, it will auto-generate BibTeX output based on the fields in the DESCRIPTION file.  This output may require some additional revision, so be careful before using the contents directly in a citation.

In order to view the package description, `packageDescription(pkgName)` will do the trick.  This will return a list of items, each based on a field from the DESCRIPTION file.  This is your best bet if you want to programmatically work with those contents.

One key issue is that the author(s) of a package and the maintainer(s) of the package may not be the same people.  If you need assistance with a package, you should contact the maintainer(s).  An example is `nlme`.  First, a snippet from the citation info:

```
> citation("nlme")

To cite package 'nlme' in publications use:

  Jose Pinheiro, Douglas Bates, Saikat DebRoy, Deepayan Sarkar and the R Development Core Team (2011). nlme: Linear and
  Nonlinear Mixed Effects Models. R package version 3.1-102.
```

And a snippet from the DESCRIPTION info:

```
> packageDescription("nlme")
Package: nlme
Title: Linear and Nonlinear Mixed Effects Models
Author: Jose Pinheiro (S version), Douglas Bates (up to 2007), Saikat DebRoy (up to 2002), Deepayan Sarkar (up to 2005), the
              R Core team.
Maintainer: R-core <R-core@R-project.org>
```

Note that the authors listed participated over different intervals, but, should you want help today, you'd email R-core@R-project.org.

Finally, as maintainers can create their own CITATION file, the CITATION info need not be a subset of the DESCRIPTION info.  An example is from `citation("base")`, which includes, among other things, the ISBN record, which is not in the output of `packageDescription("base")`.

---

Update 1.  If you'd like to show some love to authors or maintainers, here is some code get a list of the most frequently named authors or maintainers, based on the output of `installed.packages()`.  (If you'd like to limit it to packages used by some code, then check out the `mvbutils` package and the `foodweb` function -- one could get crazy and further rank by the frequency of calls or time spent, if using `Rprof`.)

Unfortunately, this code doesn't split strings into multiple names, so a collaboration is treated as 1 "person", possibly  undercounting the work of individuals.  If you want a careful analysis, you'll have to do a little more work.  :)

```
getMaint <- function(x){
    return(packageDescription(x)$Maintainer)
}

getAuth <- function(x){
    return(packageDescription(x)$Author)
}

nicePrint   <- function(x, N = 10){
    tmpTable    <- head(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE), N)
    tmpTable    <- as.data.frame(tmpTable)
    colnames(tmpTable) = "count"
    return(tmpTable)
}

vPkgs <- installed.packages()[,"Package"]

listA   <- mapply(getAuth, vPkgs)
listM   <- mapply(getMaint, vPkgs)

nicePrint(listA)
nicePrint(listM)
```

Here's an example from one computer; apologies for the ugly obscured email addresses.  The code above produces the correct email addresses from the DESCRIPTION file, but I've edited them out.

Authors:

> ```
> nicePrint(listA)
>                                                      count
> Diethelm Wuertz and many others, see the SOURCE file    14
> Hadley Wickham <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                     7
> R Development Core Team and contributors worldwide       7
> Henrik Bengtsson <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                     4
> Revolution Analytics                                     4
> Brian Ripley <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>.                    3
> David Scott <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                     3
> Luke Tierney <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                       3
> R Development Core Team                                  3
> ```

Maintainers:

> ```
> nicePrint(listM)
>                                                  count
> Rmetrics Core Team <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>    19
> R Core Team <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                  13
> Brian Ripley <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                 9
> Achim Zeileis <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>          7
> Hadley Wickham <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                 7
> Torsten Hothorn <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>      7
> David Scott <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                 5
> Henrik Bengtsson <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                 5
> Trevor Hastie <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                  5
> Luke Tierney <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>                   4
> ```

Answer (score 13):

To be able to cite R or a package, use `citation`.

```
citation()        #for base packages or R itself
citation("nlme")
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a second. :)

Comment: Also gives you the appropriate bibTeX reference, very nice.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp That's the point of the citation package.  It either takes an existing citation file or auto-construct a citation based on the DESCRIPTION file.

Answer (score 10):

use

```
packageDescription("base")
```

and read...

Comment: Or just subset `packageDescription("base")$Author` ;-)

Comment: As `citation()` is based on the DESCRIPTION file, absent a citation file, this is the correct answer.  NB: it might be good to replace `base` with a specific package name or `pkg`, so that others realize the generality of this answer.

Answer (score 10):

Some cleaning needed, but you get the idea. :)

```
library(RCurl)
gg <- getURL("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/index.html")
gg <- readLines(textConnection(gg))
gg[grep("Author:", gg)+1]
 [1] "<td>Andrie de Vries</td></tr>"
```

Richie beat me to it, but here's a short way of extracting some information using `citation`.

```
citation("ggdendro")$author
[1] "Andrie de Vries <XXXXX@XXXXX.com>"
```

In comments, Hadley suggested another method of reading straight from the DESCRIPTION file.

```
> gg <- read.dcf(url("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/DESCRIPTION"))
> gg[, "Maintainer"]
                           Maintainer 
"Andrie de Vries <xxxxx@xxxxx.com>"
```

Comment: What's nice about this answer is that it works on uninstalled packages.

Comment: @BenBolker `read.dcf(url("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/DESCRIPTION"))` is even nicer.

Comment: Thanks, @Hadley! If you don't mind, I'm appending this to the above answer for completeness.